# Gitlab doesn't loads new ssl cert and key

Tags: docker, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'm running Gitlab:13.12.15-ce.0 in docker container with my private ssl certs and key. But it's expired few days back and i have updated the .crt and .key files in /etc/gitlab/ssl directory but Gitlab still throws error that my certs are expired with loading old certs.

I have tried updating the cert and key file by following [Update the SSL Certificates](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#update-the-ssl-certificates)

I followed these steps to configure certs and key initially:[manually-configuring-https](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#manually-configuring-https)

How do i load new updated ssl cert in Gitlab ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was actually a load balancer issue, we have configured the old ssl certificate by mistake assuming it's the new ssl certificate.
After configuration of new ssl certificate in load balancer it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

From [SSL settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html), you might need to cleanup `/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs` first, putting your new key in `/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs`, and do a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

That should create the expected symlinks in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs` and update your SSL cert used by your GitLab instance..

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VonC but It doesn't resolves the issue. it's throwing same error.

Comment: @JaySingh Strange. That means your NGiNX still uses the old certificate. Not sure why.

Comment: This saved the day!! I just added my root ca certificates in my docker compose file for gitlab and mounted them with the .crt extensions at /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs. That's it, really. Then the gitlab docker image entrypoint script took care of the rest.

Comment: @Pv66 Well done!

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming this is already resolved but my suggestion is that nginx wasn't actually getting restarted. I've found that I sometimes have to force an nginx restart for it to pick up the new cert.

Comment: This answer could have been a comment.